# Disable New Relic for AMP pages?

Tags: php, newrelic

New Relic PHP extension adds inline script tags on webpages. That's invalid for AMP pages.

How can I disable New Relic only for webpages with URL ending with "/amp".

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the New Relic PHP API method call  [newrelic_disable_autorum()](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-api#api-rum-disable). This will allow you to disable the Automatic insertion of the Javascript required for page load timing for hte transaction in which the call is made. Keep in mind it will eliminate data gathering when this call is made.

Answer (score -2):

A good way of solving the problem :D

Is like saying

"Oh I have a broken finger what can I do?"
"Oh cut your entire arm!"

You can simply use NewRelic API blocking the instrumentation for those pages like

- newrelic_disable_autorum()
- NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.DisableBrowserMonitoring()
- etc etc

depending on your Agent Language

Comment: You should have given credit to the original author of this comment: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-amp-new-relic-incompatible-21954.html#comment-2631480956